# How to change source file path in jest coverage report

Tags: jestjs

I have multiple NodeJs packages in structure like

```
//repoRoot/CompA
//repoRoot/CompB
//repoRoot/CompC
```

I know this might sound really weird, but, I have dockerfile with parameters and run it three times, like

```
FROM myImg
ARG SourceDir
WORKDIR /workspace
COPY SourceDir/. .
RUN yarn test (this calls `jest --config jestconfig.json --coverage`)
```

And I wanted combine the resulting coverage reports.
Copying the files are easy, but, source file paths inside the coverage reports is like

```
/workspace/src/file1.js
/workspace/src/file2.js
```

When I wanted them to be

```
/workspace/CompA/src/file1.js
/workspace/CompA/src/file2.js
```

How should I accomplish this?
Is there a jest configuration I can do this? Or do I really need to do some string replace for all the reports?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

NVM, instead of using jest config. I just use `sed` to replace the string instead.

Comment: every body uses a sed to correct these file path... which is kinda boring, they should fix this ...